# Error downloading modules: Error loading modules: error downloading 'ssh://git@bitbucket.org/project/repo.git':

Tags: terraform

I am running into an issue with pulling a terraform module from a remote source. When I try to run `terraform init` I get the following error:

Error downloading modules: Error downloading modules: Error loading modules: error downloading 'ssh://git@bitbucket.org/project/repo.git': /usr/bin/git exited with 128: Cloning into

This takes place inside of a docker container using `golang:1.15`. According to this github issue my formatting is correct:https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/18541. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.